# Reduced relative clause extraposition

Tags: relative-clauses, reduced-relative-clauses, extraposition

I wrote:

> In PerTreebank each element of a compound verb is shown separately **and is attached** to a phrasal category named **MV**

Could I write it as:

> In PerTreebank each element of a compound verb is shown separately **attached** to a phrasal category named **MV**

In the second version I reduced "is attached" to "attached" but it is far from the name it modifies

---

**Update**: To show an example of a Persian compound verb and how its elements can be separated, I attached the following picture (read right to left)
The meaning almost is:

> We should **make** ourselves **ready** for strange things and unfamiliar ways.

*make ready* is a compound verb and *for strange....* are dependent on *ready*, while *we* is dependent on *make*. (*we, should, ourselves* parts are not in the picture, as the picture is partial)
[image]

Comment: A comma before **attached** in the second sentence would improve readability.

Comment: @JavaLatte you mean with comma it is grammatically correct?

Comment: What do you actually mean? Are all verbs in the construction 'sisters', attached to the *same* MV, or is each verb attached to a different MV? If the latter, what is the relationship between the MVs?

Comment: @StoneyB Given to the first example, I thought the subject of the sentence after **and** should be "each element of a compound verb". Thus, I concluded that OP means "each element of a compound verb" is attached to PCNMV. I think, there is only one MV category which contains all of those elements.

Comment: @StoneyB There is one MV, and the elements of a compound verb are governed by it (are under it). however, the non-verbal element may not be directly connected to the MV node, it could be part of, for example, a PP and then PP is connected to MV.

Comment: @StoneyB what about *In PerTreebank each element of a compound verb is shown separately, although they are governed by a phrasal category named MV*

Comment: @Ahmad Gotcha. And just because I'm curious: are the 'arguments' of the  compound verb--Subject, Object, &c--represented as dependents of MV or of some other category?

Comment: @StoneyB In the question I brought an example of a compound verb (Phrase structure). As I know, the light verb is usually the head and the arguments are dependent on it. the non-verbal element is also dependent of the light verb (in one analysis I saw), however it can itself takes some dependents (as in picture above)

Comment: @StoneyB I translated the sentence of the picture in question.

Comment: Very cool! So the two 'elements' there are V and ADJPC?

Comment: @StoneyB no! the two elements are V and Adj. but some other elements intervened there. they are more close to Adj as "ready *for strange things AND unfamiliar ways* constitute the ADJPC.

Comment: Hmmm ... but the dependency you are describing is not what the graphic depicts: ADJ is not 'attached' to MV but to ADJPC. It looks to me like you're describing a dependency analysis and the graphic is describing a constituency analysis.

Comment: @StoneyB sure, in the question I also said its a constituency structure (phrase structure), However I know also the associated dependency structure. Anyway, MV is in the constituency structure.

Comment: As long as you and your readers share the understanding that the structure you're describing participates in both constituency and dependency analyses, it's fine; we have the same problem in English grammar with constant squabbles over how to name/describe/parse "phrasal verbs".

Comment: @StoneyB I just saw such squabbles in one of my recent questions. I don't know what is your problem with them, some of you even try to deny their existence, but languages go their own way.

Comment: I wouldn't use *attached* to explain such a tree. I may write it like this: *In the PerTreebank, all elements of a compound verb have their own terminal nodes, all of which share the same ancestor, an MV node.*

Answer (score 2):

Both of your sentences are grammatical, and they both seem to describe the same construction; but they don't mean quite the same thing.

> ... each element ... is shown separately and is attached ... *Here you have a conjoined predicate—in effect, two predicates sharing the same subject:*

```
                        is shown separately 
      each element  and    
                        is attached ...
```

> ... each element ... is shown separately attached ... *Here you have a single predicate:*

```
      each element  is shown separately attached ...
```

In this case, *separately* and *attached* cannot be taken as two distinct predicates: we parse *separately* as an adverb modifying attached.

Note in particular that *attached ...* cannot be taken as a 'reduced relative clause' = *which is attached ...* because **a)** there's no noun in the predicate which it can modify<sup>†</sup>, and **b)** in any case, there's no relative clause in your original to reduce.

JavaLatte's suggestion of a comma following *separately* presents an adequate solution:

> ... each element ... is shown separately, attached ...

The comma marks *attached ...* as a supplement outside the core structure of the main clause. It is parsed as an adjectival participle clause, and may be taken either as a 'gloss' on *separately* or as a second, subordinated predicate—in this case they amount to pretty much the same thing.

---

<sup>†</sup> In theory the main clause itself could be the 'fallback' referent, but that would be semantically nonsensical—you can't attach the act of showing to a syntactic category!

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer, actually my main intention was with comma, then you say with comma it is almost like "and is attached"? can I conclude in such situations ("and is ...ed"), I can reduce that to ". ..ed"?

Comment: @Ahmad Fersher, as long as you put the comma in.